# What's the difference between & vs && and | vs || in R?

Tags: r, operands

What's the difference between & vs && and | vs || in R? I'm getting the same results.

```
x = 1
y = 2
z = 3
ifelse(x < y & y < z, "true","false")
ifelse(x < y && y < z, "true","false")
```

Comment: Try `1 < 2 & 3 > c(1, 4)` versus `1 < 2 && 3 > c(1, 4)` to see the difference, and read `?base::Logic`.

Comment: It looks like & checks both conditions and && only checks the first one. Thank you.